# ¿Cómo recuperar archivos borrados con el comando del? (CMD)

Tags: cmd

Acabo de borrar por accidente unos archivos usando el comando **del** de CMD. Los he intentado recuperar con software pero no los encuentran. He usado un programa que se llama Recuva y otro que se llama Data Recovery Wizard.

¿Conecen alguna forma de recuperar los archivos borrados con este comando?

------5 horas mas tarde------

Bueno, llegué a una conclusión. Si queren borrar algo y que no quede ni rastro usen el comando **del**. He usado 4 programas de recuperación de archivos y ninguno pudo localizarlos...

Comment: Agrego a tu lista `Wise data recovery` y `Free Undelete` para que los busques y pruebes. No hacen magia, si el espacio que ocupaba el archivo borrado fue ocupado por algún otro archivo, lamentablemente no vas tener forma de recuperarlo. Dicho esto, te comento  que está no es una pregunta valida para la temática del sitio y además veo que no has aceptado ninguna respuesta a las preguntas que te han hecho, te recuerdo leer: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers. Saludos y suerte.

Comment: Hola!! Gracias por contestar... a ver, me acabas de decir un par de cosas que me han dejado en 33. ¿Mi lista?¿Me han hecho preguntas que no he contestado?... bfff ¿Donde veo esas cosas? Llevo poco tiempo en esta comundad, creo que aun no sé usarla bien...

Comment: A vale... lo de la lista lo acabo de entender... ¿Donde veo eso de las preguntas que me han hecho?

Comment: Ok, Ya leí lo del link... Simpre voto a las repuestas que me hacen... las que no he votado es porque me las he contestado a mi mismo y el sistema no me deja votarme a mi mismo. Puedes comprobarlo si quieres, solo tienes que ir a mis preguntas y ver.

Comment: Todos fuimos y seremos nuevos en algo, no te preocupes. Puedes aceptar tus propias respuestas pasado creo que dos días. Saludos.